perf - Number of monitored Events > PMCs available
currently, I am trying out perf for monitoring PMCs.
Executing dmesg | grep "PMU driver" returns 7 available counters:
hw perfevents: enabled with armv8_pmuv3 PMU driver, 7 counters available.
There is no error when executing the following command:
perf stat -e L1-dcache-loads,L1-dcache-load-misses,branch-load-misses,dTLB-load-misses,branch-misses,l1d_cache_err,l1i_cache_err,br_mis_pred,l1d_cache,l1i_cache,l2d_cache -I 1000

Even though I use more than 7 events, the monitoring works just fine, why is this the case? In my understanding every PMC should monitor only one Event and therefore perf should be able to monitor 7 events only.
